# Is it possible to use Content Porter 2009 SP2 to help translation?

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, localization

We've delivered a large site in Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 and our client is looking at rolling at a language variation.

We don't have Translation Manager in place and the client would like to extract all their content, send it away and then import it.

I know we could write something but I wondered if it was possible to leverage Content Port 2009 SP2?

1. Extract components from the "global" publication.
2. Send component Xml for translation.
3. Localise components in the child publication Tridion.
4. Import back into child publication, using item Mappings to change the ImportContext to change the publication part of the path to the child publication.

Would that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you localize it at source and send separate package for translation then import it in the destination after translation?

i think that would avoid any risk.

Comment: That sounds like a fair use case, and I agree that it is a nice option to use Content Porter to export and import the translated content.

Comment: Genius - think I was definitely guilty of over engineering!

Comment: Do you need to localise it before doing the export? This could be hundreds of Components. Can't you just export it at the child (language) Publication. When you import it, then it should localise the Component. Also, I guess it depends on your required functionality... What if you need to find the Components used by a set of pages, or if you have Structure Group or Page Metadata that needs translating too. A custom tool (using the Import/Export webservice) may give you more control.